# Im Trying to get Apple Script to Read A file and tell me if certain key words are in there

Tags: file, applescript

I've gotten this far but I don't know what to do next if you know.

Can you please make edits to the script and then post the script back?

```
    on TerrorChecker()
    tell application "Finder"
        read ("/ Users / BenEvans / desktop / Test")
        if "Blue,Red,Yellow" then display dialog "Terror Alert" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    end tell
    do
    Nothing


end TerrorChecker
TerrorChecker()     
    end TerrorChecker
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assumed there's a file contains the keyword "darkness", try this one:

```
set fileContent to (read (choose file))

if "darkness" is in fileContent then
    display dialog "terror alert" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
else
    say "no keyword found"
end if
```

btw, the command read cannot handle property file, e.g. *.pdf, *.xls

then try this one:

set fileContent to (read (choose file))

```
if "blue" is in fileContent then
    display dialog "terror alert" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
else if "red" is in fileContent then
    display dialog "terror alert" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
else if "yellow" is in fileContent then
    display dialog "terror alert" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
else
    say "no keyword found"
end if
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: So its working now but it will only work if the two or three words that i put as the key words are right next to eachother

Comment: Benjamin, you'll have to do a bit more work to process a list of words. First, use an AppleScript list of words like so {"Blue", "Red", "Yellow"}. Then in your code process each word in the list and set a boolean if it was found. Your processing will differ slightly depending if your intent is that ALL words are found or if AT LEAST ONE of the words is present.

Comment: try the new one :)

Comment: Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

Your example was a little bit of a mess, so I've modified it below.

```
on run
    TerrorChecker()
end run

on TerrorChecker()
    tell application "Finder"
        set theData to read "/Users/BenEvans/Desktop/Test"
        if theData contains "Blue,Red,Yellow" then
            display dialog "Terror Alert" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        end if
    end tell
end TerrorChecker
```